# What happened to the Roddenberry's script "The God Thing"?

Tags: star-trek

During a clicking-while-bored session I came across the Den of Geek article [Planet of The Titans: The Star Trek Movie You Never Saw](http://www.denofgeek.com/us/movies/star-trek/253770/planet-of-the-titans-the-star-trek-movie-you-never-saw) and saw the following passage:

> Suddenly intrigued, Shatner asked Roddenberry what the film was going to be about. Roddenberry explained that it would be set a number of years after the series, to explain why the cast suddenly looked so much older. James T. Kirk was now a commander, while the rest of the Enterprise crew had also climbed through the ranks. The story which followed was high-concept stuff even for Roddenberry.
>
> > "One  day  a  force  comes  toward  Earth - might  be  God,  might  be  the  devil - breaking everything in its path, except the minds of the starship commanders. So we gotta find all  the  original  crewmen  for  the  starship  Enterprise,  but  first - where  is  Spock?  He's back  on  Vulcan,  doing  R&R;  five  year  mission - seven  years  of  R&R.  He  swam  back upstream. So we gotta go get him."
>
> This was part of a script that Roddenberry called The God Thing, a story that imagined the almighty as a machine floating through space, reiterating the laws of the universe in different forms for different epochs. Two-thousand years ago, the alien intelligence had taught those laws to the people of Earth by appearing as Jesus. The God Thing would have seen Kirk and his cohorts encountering this shape-shifting entity as it morphs through various forms; the mysterious god-machine has apparently malfunctioned, like a skipping record player.
>
> It was a bold idea, alright, but all a bit much for Paramount.
>
> This was after all, a script in which Spock says, "If this is your God, he's not very impressive... He demands worship every seven days. He goes out and creates faulty humans and then blames them for his own mistakes. He's a poor excuse for a Supreme Being."

---

**Question:** What happened to the original script for *The God Thing*? Is it still under wraps, or is it possibly readable somewhere by the general public?

Comment: Wikipedia repeatedly refers to the "script" as a "treatment" (e.g. a script outline with some dialogue). This suggests that there's no completed script; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_God_Thing

Comment: http://www.missionlogpodcast.com/discovereddocuments/s016/Star-Trek-II-Script.pdf

Comment: http://theomegasector.com/index.php?/topic/19348-star-trek-the-god-thing-a-look-at-gene-roddenberrys-unfilmed-trek-script/

Comment: Do you mean the original *physical* script or are you just after a copy you can read somewhere?

Comment: @Valorum the latter. I'm asking about the text, not the physical script. I'd like to know if there is something readable somewhere, somehow. I'm going to take a look at your other links now, thanks!

Comment: Ah, ok. The script appears to have been adapted into "In Thy Image" which you can read in [Star Trek II: The Lost Series](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Trek_Phase_II:_The_Lost_Series). I'm not sure how much of the original "God Thing" script survived though.

Comment: @Valorum I didn't know about any of that. I'll look for a copy, thank you! If nothing else surfaces, all of this together could potentially serve as answer.

Comment: @Valorum nothing else has since surfaced so far...

Comment: and "In Thy Image" was partly adapted into The Motion Picture